# JavaScript Location Without GETs

Tags: url, tracking

I am using this javascripts for tracking certain url.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(document.location.toString()=="http://www.mysite.com/DisplayCart.aspx")
....
....
```

but my problem is that
if i want to track group of page for example 
http://www.mysite.com/PaymentDetails.aspx?Id=817328&PaymentMode=COD&delvoption=ship&ChildStoreID=

http://www.mysite.com/PaymentDetails.aspx?Id=817329&PaymentMode=COD&delvoption=ship&ChildStoreID=

and so on..

here all url differs after aspx? 
its is just like customer specific pages/customer's order specific pages
plz note that i want to use only javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by tracking this urls? Did you consider [parsing the url](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/61/parse-query-string-by-pure-javascrirpt/) and track the returned object?

Comment: actually i want to show certain block of html code on all the payment details page, for every order for every customer..the constraint is i don't have access for .aspx page but i have for javascript which is called in header.hence i am using $(document).ready(function(){
if(document.location.toString()=="http://www.mysite.com/DisplayCart.aspx")   that means if page is bla..bla..bla.. then take action.. i mean i want that javascript read the url appear in url-address-bar and if its http://www.mysite.com/PaymentDetails.aspx?BLA-BLA-BLA-BLA... then show  html block there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Christian Stewart unfortunately that didn't work but the code below is working for me. Hope it will be bug fee in every case, i am just testing it for every possible cases of url....also let me know if you find that it  may not work in certain case...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var align1 = document.location.toString(),

    delimiter = '?',
    start = 0,
    tokens1 = align1.split(delimiter).slice(start);

//alert(tokens1[0]);

//if(document.location.toString().Split("?")[0]=="http://www.mysite.com/DisplayCart.aspx")
if(tokens1[0]=="http://www.mysite.com/DisplayCart.aspx")
{
    alert("hi");
}
else{}
});
```

And Ya thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string by ?:

```
if(document.location.toString().Split("?")[0]=="http://www.mysite.com/DisplayCart.aspx")
```

Basically, you get the two parts separated by ?, and compare just the first part.